# font-size changes position of element

Tags: html, css

I've this list of buttons

```css
button {
    background-color: grey;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0.8px #C0CBD1;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    font: 500 16px/36px sans-serif;
}

.special {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button>A</button>
<button>B</button>
<button class="special">C</button>
```

Now what I've done is that the special button has a bigger font-size. The weird thing is that increasing the `font-size` moves this button up. I guess this is all very logic but cannot find the explanation (which should help me to fix this of course!)

Comment: Vertical-align http://jsfiddle.net/q640e8sc/1/ .... because the default value baseline is based on text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The explanation is that buttons are inline-element, and the text in the button determines the vertical alignment.

The default vertical alignment for inline elements is to place the bottom of characters on the base line of the text. If you look at the buttons in your example, you see that the bottom of the characters line up exactly.

If you add some text around the buttons, you see that the text of the buttons aligns with the text outside the buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/q640e8sc/4/

If you specify a different verical alignment for the buttons, they will line up differently. If you for example use `vertical-align: middle;`, the buttons will line up at the center of the characters, so the edges of the buttons will line up: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/q640e8sc/5/

Another way to avoid that alignment is to make the buttons block elements, for example using `float: left;`. That makes the buttons line up, but it of course make the buttons react differently to surrounding elements: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/q640e8sc/6/

Answer (score 5):

Use `vertical-align`:

```css
button {
    background-color: grey;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0.8px #C0CBD1;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    font: 500 16px/36px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.special {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button>A</button>
<button>B</button>
<button class="special">C</button>
```

And to align the text in the middle, you may use `line-height`.

```css
button {
    background-color: grey;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0.8px #C0CBD1;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    font: 500 16px/36px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.special {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button>A</button>
<button>B</button>
<button class="special">C</button>
<button>D</button>
<button>E</button>
```